# How to send daily block reports from assp?

Tags: email

I use [assp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/assp/) as Mail filter and I want to automatically send daily block report from assp to each mail user.

I've set the `BlockReportFile` parameter as: `file:files/blockreportlist.txt`

My `blockreportlist.txt` has the following records:

```
user1@mydomain.com=>user1@mydomain.com
user2@mydomain.com=>user2@mydomain.com
```

But it doesn't work when I check "`Generate a BlockReport from BlockReportFile Now (BlockReportNow)`" and click "`Run now!`"

The following message is showed:

```
*** Updated - task was started
```

But the reports are not generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my `blockreportlist.txt` to:

```
*@mydomain.com
```

Comment: Is that the solution, or an update to the question? If the latter, please edit your question instead.

Comment: It's the solution.
But I can accept my own answer only in 22 hours.